# Spring Boot 2 + Apache Shiro CGLIB proxy

Tags: spring-boot, shiro

Did anyone get Apache Shiro to work with Spring Boot 2?

Shiro depends on an old version of Spring and is causing some of my beans to be proxied, resulting in errors like the one below.

> 2019-01-01 16:15:20,713 DEBUG [restartedMain] org.springframework.boot.diagnostics.LoggingFailureAnalysisReporter: Application failed to start due to an exception
>                   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanNotOfRequiredTypeException: Bean named 'prescriptionService' is expected to be of type 'com.nusrcraft.flexinics.feature.clinic.prescription.PrescriptionService' but was actually of type 'com.sun.proxy.$Proxy92'

Can work around this error with a hack: creating interfaces for the beans that are proxied - but will not apply this solution in production.

> Using org.apache.shiro:shiro-spring-boot-starter:1.4.0
>
> 2019-01-01 16:15:20,713 DEBUG [restartedMain] org.springframework.boot.diagnostics.LoggingFailureAnalysisReporter: Application failed to start due to an exception
>                   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanNotOfRequiredTypeException: Bean named 'prescriptionService' is expected to be of type 'com.nusrcraft.flexinics.feature.clinic.prescription.PrescriptionService' but was actually of type 'com.sun.proxy.$Proxy92'

full trace:

```
 2019-01-01 16:15:20,711 DEBUG [restartedMain] org.springframework.boot.diagnostics.FailureAnalyzers: FailureAnalyzer org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.HikariDriverConfigurationFailureAnalyzer@f0a4f33 failed
 java.lang.TypeNotPresentException: Type org.springframework.jdbc.CannotGetJdbcConnectionException not present
     at sun.reflect.generics.factory.CoreReflectionFactory.makeNamedType(CoreReflectionFactory.java:117)
     at sun.reflect.generics.visitor.Reifier.visitClassTypeSignature(Reifier.java:125)
     at sun.reflect.generics.tree.ClassTypeSignature.accept(ClassTypeSignature.java:49)
     at sun.reflect.generics.visitor.Reifier.reifyTypeArguments(Reifier.java:68)
     at sun.reflect.generics.visitor.Reifier.visitClassTypeSignature(Reifier.java:138)
     at sun.reflect.generics.tree.ClassTypeSignature.accept(ClassTypeSignature.java:49)
     at sun.reflect.generics.repository.ClassRepository.getSuperclass(ClassRepository.java:90)
     at java.lang.Class.getGenericSuperclass(Class.java:777)
     at org.springframework.core.ResolvableType.getSuperType(ResolvableType.java:466)
     at org.springframework.core.ResolvableType.as(ResolvableType.java:455)
     at org.springframework.core.ResolvableType.forClass(ResolvableType.java:1037)
     at org.springframework.boot.diagnostics.AbstractFailureAnalyzer.getCauseType(AbstractFailureAnalyzer.java:58)
     at org.springframework.boot.diagnostics.AbstractFailureAnalyzer.analyze(AbstractFailureAnalyzer.java:34)
     at org.springframework.boot.diagnostics.FailureAnalyzers.analyze(FailureAnalyzers.java:114)
     at org.springframework.boot.diagnostics.FailureAnalyzers.reportException(FailureAnalyzers.java:107)
     at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.reportFailure(SpringApplication.java:848)
     at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.handleRunFailure(SpringApplication.java:832)
     at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:327)
     at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1260)
     at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1248)
     at com.nusrcraft.flexinics.FlexinicsWebApplication.main(FlexinicsWebApplication.java:37)
     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
     at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
     at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartLauncher.run(RestartLauncher.java:49)
 Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.jdbc.CannotGetJdbcConnectionException
     at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
     at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
     at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
     at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:348)
     at sun.reflect.generics.factory.CoreReflectionFactory.makeNamedType(CoreReflectionFactory.java:114)
     ... 25 common frames omitted
 2019-01-01 16:15:20,713 DEBUG [restartedMain] org.springframework.boot.diagnostics.LoggingFailureAnalysisReporter: Application failed to start due to an exception
 org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanNotOfRequiredTypeException: Bean named 'prescriptionService' is expected to be of type 'com.nusrcraft.flexinics.feature.clinic.prescription.PrescriptionService' but was actually of type 'com.sun.proxy.$Proxy92'
     at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1247)
     at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1164)
     at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:593)
     at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:90)
     at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessProperties(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:374)
     at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1378)
     at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:575)
     at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:498)
     at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:320)
     at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
     at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:318)
     at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199)
     at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:846)
     at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:863)
     at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:546)
     at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:142)
     at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:775)
     at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:397)
     at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:316)
     at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1260)
     at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1248)
     at com.nusrcraft.flexinics.FlexinicsWebApplication.main(FlexinicsWebApplication.java:37)
     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
     at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
     at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartLauncher.run(RestartLauncher.java:49)
```

Comment: plz post your code and config